# In Pandas, how to operate between columns in max perfornace

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
     usersidid  clienthostid    LoginDaysSumLastMonth   LoginDaysSumLast7Days LoginDaysSum
0       9            1                50                          7              1728
1       3            1                43                          3              1331
2       6            1                98                          9               216
3       4            1                10                          6                64
4       9            2                64                          32              343
5       12           3                45                          43             1000
6       8            3                87                          76              512
7       9            3                16                          3              1200
```

What I'm trying to do is:

For every 'clienthostid' look for the 'usersidid' with the highest 'LoginDaysSum', I check if there is a usersidid which is the highest LoginDaysSum in two different clienthostid (for instance, usersidid = 9 ia the highest LoginDaysSum in both clienthostid 1, 2 and 3 in rows 0, 4 and 7 accordingly).

In this case, I want to choose the higher LoginDaysSum (in the example it would be the row with 1728), lets call it maxRT.

I want to calculate the ratio of LoginDaysSumLast7Days between maxRT and each of the other rows (in example, it would be rows index 7 and 4).

If the ratio is below 0.8 than I want to drop the row:

index 4- LoginDaysSumLast7Days_ratio = 7/32  <  0.8      //row will drop!

index 7- LoginDaysSumLast7Days_ratio = 7/3  > 0.8        //row will stay!

The same condition also will be applied of LoginDaysSumLastMonth.

So for the example the result will be:

```
     usersidid  clienthostid    LoginDaysSumLastMonth   LoginDaysSumLast7Days LoginDaysSum
0       9            1                50                          7              1728
1       3            1                43                          3              1331
2       6            1                98                          9               216
3       4            1                10                          6                64
5       12           3                45                          43             1000
6       8            3                87                          76              512
7       9            3                16                          3              1200
```

Now here's the snag- performance is critical.
I tried to implement it using .apply but not only i couldn't make it to work right, it also ran way too slow :(

My code so far (forgive me of it's written terribly wrong, I only started working for the first time with SQL, Pandas and Python last week and everything I learned is from examples I found here ^_^):

```
df_client_Logindayssum_pairs = df.merge(df.groupby(['clienthostid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].max(),df, how='inner', on=['clienthostid', 'LoginDaysSum'])
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = df_client_Logindayssum_pairs.groupby(['usersidid'], as_index=False, sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].count().rename(columns={'LoginDaysSum': 'NumOfClientsPerUesr'})
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = UsersWithMoreThan1client[UsersWithMoreThan1client.NumOfClientsPerUesr >= 2]
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = df_client_Logindayssum_pairs[df_client_Logindayssum_pairs.usersidid.isin(UsersWithMoreThan1Device.loc[:, 'usersidid'])].reset_index(drop=True)
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = UsersWithMoreThan1client.sort_values(['clienthostid', 'LoginDaysSum'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSumLast7Days'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index(name='ratio')
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = UsersWithMoreThan1client[UsersWithMoreThan1client.ratio > 0.8]
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = ttm.groupby(['clienthostid'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSumLastMonth'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index(name='ratio2')
    UsersWithMoreThan1client = UsersWithMoreThan1client[UsersWithMoreThan1client.ratio2 > 0.8]
```

Would very much appreciate any suggestions on how to do it

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your desired output with the example you've given, and also show your code using apply?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my Q accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
# Put the index as a regular column
data = data.reset_index()
# Find greates LoginDaysSum for each clienthostid
agg1 = data.sort_values(by='LoginDaysSum', ascending=False).groupby(['clienthostid']).first()
# Collect greates LoginDaysSum for each usersidid
agg2 = agg1.sort_values(by='LoginDaysSum', ascending=False).groupby('usersidid').first()
# Join both previous aggregations
joined = agg1.set_index('usersidid').join(agg2, rsuffix='_max')
# Compute ratios
joined['LoginDaysSumLast7Days_ratio'] = joined['LoginDaysSumLast7Days_max'] / joined['LoginDaysSumLast7Days']
joined['LoginDaysSumLastMonth_ratio'] = joined['LoginDaysSumLastMonth_max'] / joined['LoginDaysSumLastMonth']
# Select index values that do not meet the required criteria
rem_idx = joined[(joined['LoginDaysSumLast7Days_ratio'] < 0.8) | (joined['LoginDaysSumLastMonth_ratio'] < 0.8)]['index']
# Restore index and remove the selected rows
data = data.set_index('index').drop(rem_idx)
```

The result in `data` is:

```
       usersidid  clienthostid  LoginDaysSumLastMonth  LoginDaysSumLast7Days    LoginDaysSum  
index                                                                                         
0              9             1                     50                      7            1728  
1              3             1                     43                      3            1331  
2              6             1                     98                      9             216  
3              4             1                     10                      6              64  
5             12             3                     45                     43            1000  
6              8             3                     87                     76             512  
7              9             3                     16                      3            1200
```

Comment: That input helped me to solve even more problems, thank you!

Comment: @O.San No problem :) If the answer solves your problem please consider marking it as accepted answer, thanks!